# App for making interactive mockup or GUI on ipad?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

Are there any apps for iPad that let me construct a graphical user interface either wysiwyg or otherwise and play with it interactively (obviously without any application logic or data)?  There are a couple apps that let me construct "linked mockups" where tapping a certain region on a slide takes me to another slide, but I'm looking for something more advanced that has various GUI widgets, and I am happy to do programming, as long as it is done 100% on iPad.

Web app suggestions are welcome too as long as they work excellently on iPad.